# Can I defeat the Eater of Worlds with only Iron Armor and a Demonite Broadsword? if not, what do I need?

Tags: terraria

The Eater of Worlds is rather tough to kill. I have iron armor and a demonite broadsword, but he eats me quickly. What equipment do I need to beat him?

Comment: Sunfury melts him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my entire process on how I've beaten the eater of worlds. It is not my intention to brag, but instead provide credibility; using these exact steps, I have defeated the eater of worlds using a brand new hardcore character without the assistance of any other players or items.

1. Obtain all of the following:

   - At least iron armor (or better) - set bonuses help
   - Gold bow
   - 250-500-ish arrows (some flaming arrows greatly help)
   - several suspicious looking eyes
   - several vacant houses for NPCs
2. Brew several archery potions, ironskin potions, regeneration potions, and healing potions
3. Under the effect of all buff potions, summon the eye of cthulhu and defeat him. Depending on how fast you are at this point in the game, you may or may not be able to defeat more than one per night. If the moon is past the halfway mark in the sky, don't summon another until the next Terrarian night.
4. After obtaining enough demonite ore, craft a war axe of the night and demonite bow.
5. Talk to the dryad to obtain purification powder, or the demolitionist to obtain bombs, and head over to the corruption. using either to access shadow orbs, break 3 of them (keep in mind the third will summon the eater of worlds). If any of these drop from shadow orbs, you can use them as weapons:

   - Musket - an excellent ranged weapon, especially for this stage of the game.
   - Ball O' Hurt - An excellent weapon to fight against the eater of worlds. Definitely a good idea to use it during the boss battle.
   - Vilethorn - if you have any mana, using this whenever possible is highly recommended. Cast it parallel to the eater of worlds' body for maximum damage.
6. When the eater of worlds is awakened, you'll want to be equipped with the following for the boss fight:

   - War axe of the night
   - Several ironskin potions, regeneration potions, and healing potions
   - Several grenades, if possible (arrows or musket would work too)
   - Any shadow orb weapons, and an ample supply of mana if using the vilethorn
7. Chances are you'll be in a pit, and this is actually a good thing since it protects you from any eaters of souls (which are a nuisance during the boss fight). Use several wooden platforms so you can navigate vertically, and start swinging your war axe or flail.
8. During battle, simply move next to or below his body when it attacks you so you can deal constant damage with your weapon. If you're confident you aren't going to hit yourself, lob a couple grenades, as they do a hefty 60-ish damage to multiple segments.
9. As segments die, they drop hearts, which are instantly collected at melee range - this greatly improves your survivability at this stage of the fight. If you die partway through, you'll still have a few shadow scales - see if you can make a piece of shadow armor, and attempt the boss battle again.

Repeat these steps until you have full shadow armor. Equipping this full set and an ironskin potion makes the battle a walk in the park. At that point, you don't even need to artfully dodge his attacks; just sit there swinging your axe and reap the rewards.

Answer (score 7):

You've got a number of options open to you (aren't sandbox games grand!):

- You could go mine out some better ores.  For instance, you should be able to dig a shaft, find Silver and/or Gold, and mine enough to make better armor.
- You could go into the Jungle and try to make some gear - the [Thorn Chakram](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Thorn_Chakram) is easy to recommend.  Jungle Armor might be tricky, as the resources required are likely going to be difficult to collect in quantity at your current health/armor level.  The Chakram is pretty straightforward and low resource cost, though.
- You could fight the [Goblin Army](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_army), which has a chance to spawn after you start breaking Shadow Orbs.  They drop [Harpoons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Harpoon), which are recommended for use against the pre-hardmode bosses and apparently make pretty short work of them.  The Army's not tough to fight if you have a pretty defensible area and a fast-firing weapon that does decent knockback.

I'd also suggest constructing a boss arena (in the corruption, if that wasn't already clear) if you haven't already.  It doesn't need to be particularly long or tall - 75 or so blocks wide and two jump-heights high should be enough.  Just put wooden platforms around the inside so that you can maneuver should the Eater dive through it.

Comment: You can't fight him an an arena that is not corrupted. I also cannot break shadow orbs since they are behind corrupted stone which an only be mined with a demonite pickaxe which requires shadow scale.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness, yes.  So you should probably build your arena in the corruption.  You can build it out of whatever, though.  I imported dirt blocks.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Actually, you can break corrupted stone.  If you kill the Eye of Cthulu, the Dryad can be an NPC, and with some purification powder, all you need is a pickaxe to get to shadow orbs.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness, In addition to what Retrosaur mentioned, you can use dynamite or bombs to break corrupted stone.  I've always fought EoW the first time by breaking 3 orbs.

Comment: So it's not necessarily a requisite to have Shadow gear to get to the Eater of Worlds

Comment: After banging my head on various explosive objects, I want to emphasize that Dryad purification powder is the way to go for dealing with corruption.

Answer (score 4):

Preferably, your ideal weapons are weapons that pierce through  multiple enemies, weapons with fast swing times, or weapons that can hit multiple times.

## First Time

**Armor**
When it comes to armor, you'd be hard pressed to find ores.  At that stage of the game, the best armor you can get is either Gold or Meteroite* armor. If you play a more Melee approach, it's best to use the Gold armor, as the set bonus grants a +3 defense.  If you play more Ranged based approach, using Meteroite Armor + Space Blaster can work wonders.

Basically, your choice of armor all comes down to your playstyle, Melee or Ranged.

*Only happens under certain conditions

**Weapons**
I find that weapons with big hitboxes work better than other weapons for the most part. Weapons that are easy to find at this level include the [Blade of Grass](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_of_Grass), and the Gold Broadsword.  Not to mention, coupled with a decent swing speed, the Blade of Grass has a 25% proc chance of causing poison, which can greatly help with your fight.

**Misc**
It's advisable to bring Accessories that grant health regen, for example, the [Band of Regeneration](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Band_of_Regeneration). Bring potions.  Always bring potions, because you never know what you need.  Ironskin potions also work wonders, granting extra defense, which increases your survivability.

## Farming

A trick I use is to combine high tier armor (typially Shadow), combined with a Flail (You can find these in Chests), combined with wooden platforms, allows you to quickly take him out without dying too easily.

Comment: I'm not sure about the armour; the EoW is the only thing that drops it, and at a 50% chance of 1-2 Shadow Scales per segment. It'll be hard to get the 45 Shadow Scales (needing about 60 segment kills) to craft Shadow Armour.

Comment: Eater of worlds drops shadow scale, so no shadow armor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get silver or gold armor.Mine around until you have enough gold or silver.

Have you tried to break ebonstone with dynamite or bombs?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a nights edge you can do one hit kills but you need at least iron for the nights edge you need a firey great sword (drag needed to mine the hell stone) you'll need a murumasa (found in dungeons) a blade of grass (stingers and green orb plant things) and a blood butcher or demonite sword.

Comment: Actually, if you're able to craft the Night's Edge, you don't even have to care about defeating that worm boss. He's weaker than Skeletron which guard Muramasa.

Comment: I agree with the above comment.  The tier of weapons to get to the Night's Edge is enough that you'd be easily able to handle the Eater of Worlds.

Answer (score 0):

If you've smashed a demon orb, you should also start getting meteorite ore.  You can make some decent armor out of it (better than any standard ore), but the real prize of meteorite ore is a Phaseblade, which has a wide swing radius and works great against Eater of Worlds.  Swing for the head to prevent him from splitting too soon.

Also with meteorite ore, you can create a few neat guns.  I favor the Space Gun, which does low damage but cuts through several parts of the Eater and can be fired rapidly.  This, with the Meteorite Armor and a lot of mana, can help get some long-range damage going.

Of course...you'll need a proper pickaxe to farm any of this (I believe Gold is required for meteorite ore), and if you feel your Nightmare Sword is good enough, you may be better served using the gold for armor.  Vilethorn down the length of it also works GREAT against the Eater, if you're lucky enough to get it from a drop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need much in the way of equipment to beat him, just grenades.  The easiest way to beat him is to build an arena above ground.  Make several levels of wooden planks on top of one another, and make it plenty long (over a screen wide).  Make sure you are still in the corruption even at the top level.  If you need to break shadow orbs to summon him, it's ideal if you have a magic mirror and can create an area where you place a bed to use as your spawn point, so you can get back quickly.

Pre 1.2, this was easy (he typically couldn't get past a certain height, and you could just rain down grenades).  The Eater has been given a bit of a buff as of 1.2, though, and he can actually get to you so be prepared to dodge.  But the tactic is the same.  Throw grenades at him.  You will damage many segments with each solid hit.

This method *can* produce lots of separate worm segments, and in 1.2 this is trickier.  But I still beat him while wearing only one piece of armor (ancient shadow mail, which I luckily scavenged) and 7 hearts.  It typically takes 30-40 grenades and I might use a bow to finish off the last few bits (gold if I am lucky, iron if not).  I then make a nightmare bow if I want to keep farming him.

I don't think it's difficult to get enough gold to buy all the grenades you need.  But it helps to start on a world with good natural caves, so spelunking with minimal digging will be very rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggested**

Place a platform(any) about 3-4 tiles above any ground, place campfire within range, heart lantern if any, wear the highest armour you have, get the strongest flail type weapon you have, hold about 15 health potions.

Use a hook to cling onto the platform and drop the flail onto the ground beneath and wait for that stupid worm to suicide. Heal when needed. Towards the end of the fight before the worm dies if you are sure of the direction it is attack from you may retract your flail and attack it directly.

Minimum gear I have done with this is Silver Set with 240 Health plus Ball O'Hurt. Took almost all of the 15 potions though.

With Gold Set(or Platinum) plus a Ball O'Hurt that have increased damage, and accessories that boost Defence. It is possible to kill it w/o a single potion.

**This DOES NOT work well on Expert**

**Iron Armour and Demonite Broadsword**

If you insist on using sword it will be significantly hard but not impossible - like any other bosses a good arena is what you need.

Find the largest open area in the corruption near the orb you need to break to summon the worm. Use dynamite **Carefully**(you do not want to summon that worm w/o building anything) to open an area if needed. Combining the Dynamite with Gel to make it sticky can remove the chance of it bouncing towards the orb and destroying it.

Build the arena multi with at least 5 tile and at most 8 tile (or less if your char cannot even reach 8) gap between each layer. Ensure campfire and heart lantern covers the entire arena(some parts near the corners can be neglected but make sure the center have bonus heal).

During the fight, if the worm attacks from below, jump to the side away from it and drop down on layer. This will result in the worm arcing over you, giving a few seconds to attack it's body. If it attacks from the side, drop and run towards it at the last moment before it reaches you an similarly you will have a few seconds to hit it. If it attacks from above, jump away from it and up one level to get opening from the worm.

Once it breaks, focus on the smaller segment(s) and completely kill it before attacking the main slower body again.

Any combat potions will be helpful, but Health potions are most important. Do Not wait for last minute heals. Use potions as long as a single potion cannot over heal you. Any others like Ironskin, Regeneration, are good to have.

Using high knock back weapons(like musket or even hammers) against small segments can force them to bounce away from you like Most flying enemies. Using on large segment only halt it momentarily(enough to prevent getting hit).

Comment: I placed more words on answer the question, but if anyone wants more details on my suggested method just drop a comment, I'll expand it

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I'd Smash one shadow orb, collect up the meteorite and make the full set of meteorite armor. Next, Buy the pistol looking gun from the arms dealer and upgrade it to the space gun. With the full set of armor, your bonus is the space gun gets infinite amo, without using mana.

Answer (score -1):

It took me maybe 30 seconds to beat him I had meteorite armour I had a molten pick axe and mined a tunnel in ebonstobe then i dug a small square i spawned Gina and all his segments went in the square then I just hit him with fiery greatsword

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the vilethorn works incredibly great. if you dont have it, just chuck grenades at him. also you should build a house in the corruption so that if you die he does not despawn. I would recommend farming this boss as he gives you great pre-hardmode armour, and gives you access to a nightmare pickaxe, so you can mine hellstone and craft a firey greatsword. also bring some ironskin potions as well as healing potions.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend gold or higher armor. A light's bane a demon bow a war ax of night. Unholy arrows are awesome for the fight the slime gun is also effective.    Bring ironskin, regeneration, archery, and health potions. That is how i defeated that boss. :)

Answer (score -2):

If on the mobile version, I suggest using flamelash because it fires continuously. I am using that always to farm the Eater of Worlds. The only thing is you need a lot of mana for that.

Answer (score -2):

I killed it with iron armour and a vile thorn I had 220 mana and i also used a few grenades but once u get the technique down its fairly easy.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you have Water Bolt or Muramasa (I killed Eater of World with that) and use Copper or higher armour. You need at least 220 Life and arena that uses platforms. If underground, you just need to kill his tail or his head, if you kill his body, he will turn into two Eater of Worlds or more.

Comment: Muramasa is only available in the dungeon, which is inaccessible until you've beaten Skeletron. Water Bolt can spawn in the "lobby" of the dungeon, but it's rare. The dungeon itself is also quite dangerous for early-game characters. If you're able to defeat Skeletron and survive the dungeon, beating Eater of Worlds should be pretty trivial, even without Muramasa.

Answer (score -2):

it can be done i did it with nothing but a wooden bow.
and a new Character

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ...and an arena, and a couple of potions.

Comment: well the only potion i used was shine potion and a hunter potion. beside that i didn't use anything that would buff my stats of a wooden bow and the whole inventory full of arrows. it took almost 3 stack of arrow to down him the second try. he kind of de-spawned the first time.  i think i spent around 20-30 min on EOW before he went down and it all happen in 1,1