# Demonic War Axe or Light's Bane, which is best against the Eater of Worlds?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I am going to attempt to kill the Eater of Worlds, but I lost the weapon (Muramasa) that I killed it with last time. So this time around I still have full silver armor, but should I use the Demonic War Axe or Light's Bane?

I have 15 hearts, Hermes boots, and Mana Flower and I am playing on my Ipad.

Comment: You might find some good info [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124684/what-equipment-do-i-need-to-kill-the-eater-of-worlds)

Comment: Suggestion wise i would use the Light's bane since it has a way higher attackspeed and only a bit lower damage. If you have some sort of piercing weapon though i would defenitly take that.

Comment: Thx a lot Marco I'm gonna go fight that thing! :D

Comment: Oh great i looked at franks thing now I need a tie breaker

Comment: Ok I defeated it with the War Axe and Ball O Hurt that I got from an orb, thank you for your help

Comment: Fought him loads of times. Most items work ^^

Answer (score 2):

I use a **Thorn Chakram**. Here's my setup:

> ■ = **Solid Block**
>   0 = **Air/You**
>   ■■■■■■
>   ■■■■■■
>   ■■ 0  0 ■■
>   ■■ 0  0 ■■
>   ■■ 0  0 ■■
>   ■■■■■■
>   ■■■■■■

**Note:** This strategy works best on **Mobile** only.

1. Enclose yourself in a 2x3 space.
   **(Make sure the walls are 2 thick, otherwise the Thorn Chakram will go outside the wall.)**
2. Summon the Eater of Worlds.
3. Aim the Thorn Chakram at the wall, doesn't matter which side.
4. Hold the fire button the entire length of the battle.
5. Just sit there until it's dead.
6. Collect the lovely loot.